# How can i check for a format of user input in sql query with a given regex format?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For example
Make a table such that user can enter either one of the two identity proofs:
Aadhaar card or Passport. 
Formats:
Aadhaar Card: NNNN NNNN NNNN
Passport: ANNNNNN , where A is Alphabet and N is Number.
If the user enters wrong format, the input should not be accepted.

Comment: Welcome. Please include a minimal code sample that shows what you have tried so far. Is there a UI in front of this database? If so, say something about it and the programming languages you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a better practice to validate the user input somewhere else (either in a frontend application or preferably in a business logic layer), but not in your database.

Having said that, it's still possible to validate incoming data and even apply changes to it using triggers. For example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER checkInputFormat 
    BEFORE INSERT ON yourTable FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.card IS NULL AND NEW.passport IS NULL) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No identity provided';
        END IF;

        IF (NEW.card IS NOT NULL AND NEW.card NOT REGEXP '^(\d{4} ){2}\d{4}$') THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid card format';
        END IF;

        IF (NEW.passport IS NOT NULL AND NEW.passport NOT REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]\d{6}$') THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid passport format';
        END IF;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This trigger will execute for each row that you try to insert in `yourTable` and check for the format of `card` and `passport` columns using regular expressions. If the format is invalid, an error will be thrown and the row won't be inserted.